# How to replace in selection using AppleScript for BBEdit?

Tags: applescript, bbedit

Is there a way to replace text within a selection using Applescript for BBEdit? I have a replace script, and I'd like to run it for only selected text. I know you can replace in selection using the find menu, but I can't find anything that says it does this in the AppleScript dictionary for BBEdit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an application's scripting dictionary, specific commands aren't necessarily declared, just their syntax and options.  Usually you can look at a command to see what the parameters are, which also defines the data types that it is expecting - in this case for example, the `replace` command has a `searching in` parameter, which can be anything.

The answer is similar to the one to [your other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985983/10853463), you just need to further define where to search.  For example, the `selection` is a property of a `window`, and a `window` is a property of a `document`:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
   tell front document
      replace "12:" using "{#pl}:" searching in its window's selection
   end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I think I understand AppleScript a lot better now. And yeah, I forgot to mention that in my original question so I thought I should create another.